# Code is working fine but error icon displayed on page in NetBeans 8.0.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, maatwebsite-excel

I am working in Laravel Project .

Code is written to export data into excel .

I am getting excel report , but error icon is not getting removed from Netbeans IDE page.

[image]

**Thank you for your contributions and if you need more screenshots or info, I'll be happy to provide it!**

Comment: Put your mouse over the error icon and post here what error it shows.

Comment: Syntax error
 unexpected: :
 after: )
 expected: {, ;
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
@EliasSoares

Comment: Your NetBeans is not configured to support your PHP version syntax.

Comment: Please use PHPStorm or VS Code. I think Netbeans is not so intelligent like these two IDEs. @EliasSoares answer is the right one.

Comment: NetBeans is for Java, and is old, do not use it for PHP, there are a lot of better free IDEs out there like Sublime Text, VSCode, Atom, and more... Also, you problem is that you are using PHP 7.0 but NetBeans is not configured to use that version.

Comment: First I will try to configure Php 7.0  .
If Netbeans  not supports , then I will look for some other IDE .
Thanks all of you ,

Comment: I Installed Netbeans 12 , Now No error .Thanks